# openssl sha256 diff

Tags: openssl, sha256

I am using openssl 1.0.1c ,  linux x86_64

i am creating file contains "hello" (without new line character)

- openssl dgst -sha256 hello_file

> i get : *5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03*

---

If i am using any other online calc ([1](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) , [2](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator) , 3  , 4 ,  5 (because of lack of reputation i cant do more hyperlinks)

> i get : *2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824*

The most confusing part is if i am trying online calculator with **"hello(new line character)"**
then

> 1 return : *5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03*

and  it is exactly what i am getting with openssl. While all others return

> 2, 3, 4 , 5 : *cd2eca3535741f27a8ae40c31b0c41d4057a7a7b912b33b9aed86485d1c84676*

I knew about new line issue with echo, but i didn't knew that each file appended with the new line.**So how can i get sha256 of file without new line character ?** And what is wrong with all other calculators ?

Thanks in advance

Kirill

---

3    convertstring.com/Hash/SHA256

4    webutils.pl/index.php?idx=sha1

5    quickhash.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, your `hello_file` has a newline:

```
$ echo 'hello' > hello_file; openssl sha256 hello_file; xxd hello_file
SHA256(hello_file)= 5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f0a                           hello.
```

Removing the new line would depend on your editor, if your situation is similar to mine when i found this post, messing with a hash of a password you can just do something like this:

```
$ echo -n 'hello' > hello_file; openssl sha256 hello_file; xxd hello_file
SHA256(hello_file)= 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f                             hello
```

You can do something like this to remove the last character(or two):

```
$ echo "hello" > hello_file; od -c hello_file; truncate hello_file --size=-1; od -c hello_file
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
```

It looks as if the other calculators are appending a dos style carriage return + new line

```
$ echo -en 'hello\r\n' > hello_file; openssl sha256 hello_file; xxd hello_file
SHA256(hello_file)= cd2eca3535741f27a8ae40c31b0c41d4057a7a7b912b33b9aed86485d1c84676
0000000: 6865 6c6c 6f0d 0a                        hello..
```

Comment: Thank you very match for answer

Comment: @yabloki The question was almost year stale when I answered, but it may help someone else down the road (I was researching the same problem). How about an accept or upvote? :)

Comment: sure ! I am sorry my every answer taking about  a half of a year )