# Different hash when using file/openssl and online hasher

Tags: hash, openssl, md5

I have a file, file.txt and inside it I have a text `computer`. When I use openssl to make a MD5 hash out of it, it gives me:

```
openssl dgst -md5 file.txt 
MD5(file.txt)= 6accefe4a7ff62bd935f25a053c5fd3c
```

And when I use http://www.md5.cz/ to make hash from the word `computer` it gives me `df53ca268240ca76670c8566ee54568a` and I dont know why.

In my file theres no newlines and spaces. What is the problem here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [MD5 hash with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6839969/608639), [openssl sha256 diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11742460/608639), [OpenSSL create SHA hash from shell stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066171/608639), [Generating a sha256 from the Linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3358420/608639), [Equivalent of md5 hashing in linux commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16446306/608639), [How to remove newline from output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35799684/608639), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 of `computer` is `df53ca268240ca76670c8566ee54568a`.

MD5 of `computer\n` is `6accefe4a7ff62bd935f25a053c5fd3c`.

Your `file.txt` is having a new line character `\n` at the end.